# Changing categorical variable to numeric

Tags: r

my data set is

```
Type
IL 
DT
DT
FC
MB
IL
```

I want to change `IL=1`, `DT=2`, `FC=3`, `MB=4`
So the result data will be

```
Type
1
2
2
3
4
1
```

Comment: `tp <- as.character(df$Type); c(factor(tp, unique(tp))` ... or something like that

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor(Type))`

Answer (score 0):

How about using `transform` ?

```
x <- c("IL", "DT", "DT", "FC", "MB", "IL")
transform(x,id=as.numeric(factor(x)))

# X_data id
#1     IL  3
#2     DT  1
#3     DT  1
#4     FC  2
#5     MB  4
#6     IL  3
```